# "Unable to create Node: timed out" error when creating node in MAAS

Tags: server, virtualbox, maas

I am trying out the new MAAS tool on my laptop and have installed the MAAS server in a VirtualBox VM. I want to try adding nodes so I created a couple of VMs in VirtualBox that boot from the network via PXE and exist on a 'host-only' network with the MAAS server. When I go to the MAAS admin website I try to add the nodes by copying the MAC address for each of the virtual machines but get the error message "Unable to create Node: timed out". Is MAAS trying to invoke the node via Wake on LAN? Is there someway to get it to work with Virtual Machines for testing purposes?

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by a very long delay by dnsmasq when it gets restarted after node additions.

Edit the `PSERV_TIMEOUT` value in the Django `settings.py` so it's 30 instead of 7.